# FATAL: password authentication failed for user with Postgres13.3 and SCRAM authentication

Tags: java, postgresql, hikaricp

I have setup a postgres:13.3 docker container and scram-sha-256 authentication.

Initially, I ran:

```
docker run -d --name my-postgres13 -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=fbp123 -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=scram-sha-256 -v pgdata13:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:13.3
```

Postgres.conf:

```
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
hostnossl all all 0.0.0.0/0 scram-sha-256
local all all scram-sha-256
```

After above done and restarted container, I created a new fbp2 user and applied password 'fbp123', and password seems to be saved as
scram in pg_authid table:

```
 16386 | fbp2                      | t        | t          | f             | f           | t           | f              | f            |           -1 | SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:yw+jyaEzlvlOjZnc/L/flA==$tqPlJIDXv9zueaGd8KpQf11N82IGgAOsK4
Lhb7lPhi4=:+mCXFKb2y5PG6ycIKCz7xaY8U5MNLnkzlPZK8pt3to0= |
```

I use the original plain-text from within my java app to connect:

```
hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
hikariConfig.setUsername("fbp2");
hikariConfig.setPassword("fbp123");
hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://%s:%s/%s".formatted("localhost", 5432, "mydb"));
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
return dataSource.getConnection();
```

From logs, this url is used: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb`

The issue is I'm having authentication issue, although I use the plain-text password that I used in postgres server:

```
2024-03-30 14:38:03.372 DEBUG 22440 [           main] c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource                 : Loaded driver with class name org.postgresql.Driver for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
2024-03-30 14:38:03.601 DEBUG 22440 [           main] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fbp2"
2024-03-30 14:38:03.601 DEBUG 22440 [           main] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fbp2"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:693)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
```

Note that If I revert to "trust" and send no passwords, I have this:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no password was provided.
```

So, it seems server only wants scram. I have tried md5 with no success.

---

Some relevant dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
   <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

My docker desktop runs on windows 11.
I use Oracle OpenJDK 20.0.1

I can connect to mydb with fbp2 user with no problem via psql admin tool (after plain password):

```
root@a00ccf79f08a:/# psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U fbp2 -d mydb
Password for user fbp2:
psql (13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

mydb=#
```

**UPDATE 1**

Server logs (includes connection attempt):

```
2024-03-30 15:21:19.566 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2024-03-30 15:21:19.567 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-03-30 15:21:19.567 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-03-30 15:21:19.571 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-03-30 15:21:19.576 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-03-30 15:21:18 UTC
2024-03-30 15:21:19.582 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

**UPDATE 2**

Result of
"mydb=# select name, setting, source, sourcefile from pg_settings where name = 'password_encryption';"

```
mydb=# select name, setting, source, sourcefile from pg_settings where name = 'password_encryption';
        name         | setting | source  | sourcefile 
---------------------+---------+---------+------------
 password_encryption | md5     | default | 
(1 row)
```

**UPDATE 3**

/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf:

```
#password_encryption = scram-sha-256        # md5 or scram-sha-256
```

I see only one postgresql.conf file. To reload the change, I did:

```
mydb=# SELECT pg_reload_conf();
 pg_reload_conf 
----------------
 t
(1 row)

mydb=#
```

and also docker restart container.

Comment: After changing to `trust`, you forgot to reload. For the original error, look at the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for helping. Just now I reverted to "trust" (commented password_encryption in postgres.conf, edited with "trust" in pg_hba.conf), run SELECT pg_reload_conf();, check logs (received SIGHUP, reloading configuration files).
Tried to connect, got: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no password was provided.
Restarted docker just in case, same.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
For the original error, my docker logs (don't see my connection attempt):

2024-03-30 15:21:19.566 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2024-03-30 15:21:19.567 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-03-30 15:21:19.567 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
 listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
 database system was shut down at 2024-03-30 15:21:18 UTC
 database system is ready to accept connections

Comment: "database system was shut down", that seems strange

Comment: Also @LaurenzAlbe, mydb=# show password_encryption; --> md5

Comment: Add the information, properly formatted, as update to question text, not in the comments. Also add the output of `select name, setting, source, sourcefile from pg_settings where name = 'password_encryption';`

Comment: This `password_encryption  md5    default ` is telling you that the postgresql.conf change is not being picked up. Either 1) You are not connecting to the right database or 2) You are setting `password_encryption = scram-sha-256` in the wrong postgresql.conf file.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, i responded with update 3. 
Also jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb is called. User string is contained in Hikari. Is that ok?

Comment: If a failed password authentication connection attempt does not end up in the log file, then the connection attempt was to a different server than the one the log file is logging for.

Comment: This `jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb` is pointing at `localhost` of wherever it is being run and from the looks of it that is not the Postgres server in the container. Bottom line is the `postgresql.conf` setting for `password_encryption` is different from what you seeing in the client, so you are not connecting to the server you think you are. Taken that as a given and work back from it.